# How do I wait for a keypress in a Qt GUI application

Tags: qt

I am writing a math practice program for my grandson.  I first wrote it as a console app as below and everything worked fine.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    n2Digit = GetNewDigit(iProblemsWorkedArray);
    int validAnswer = add(n1Digit, n2Digit);
    bool noKey = true;
    while(noKey)
    {
        char KeyPressed = getch();
        int KeyAscii = KeyPressed;
        if((KeyAscii >= 48) && (KeyAscii <= 57) && (validAnswer < 10))
        {
            studentAnswer = KeyAscii - 48;
            noKey = false;
        }

      yada yada...

    }
}
```

Now I want to write the same thing using the Qt GUI, but found that the

```
   char KeyPressed = getch();
```

within the while loop no longer works in GUI mode.

I have searched for days and come to the conclusion that I must be phrasing the search wrong.  Would someone please help ?

Comment: In GUI you do not work with loops directly, in Qt you work with signals and slots. Could you explain what your objective is?

Comment: In Qt you use widget where you can write and this generates a series of signals, I recommend you check QLineedit

Comment: An example... The user is presented with a series of addition problems of the form 3 + x = where x is represented by the digits 0 through 9. The first would be 3 + 0 = __ the user types his answer (not using the enter key. As soon as he hits the 3 key, the next problem appears 3 + 1 = __ and the user types in his answer and the next problem appears. This continues for each of the digits 0..9. I need to wait for each answer, but do not know how to do that without the program freezing up during the wait.  And thanks for your help.  n1 + n2 = n3  (these are lineEdits.)

Comment: In my program snippit from above, say that n1 has been set to 3.  the for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) loop will set n2 equal to 0.  I then must wait for the user to type in n3 as his answer, evaluate it for correctness, play a "hurrah" if correct or "uhoh" if wrong.  Then the loop goes on to the next n2 and repeat.....

 I have written a void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event) and can detect each numeric key (0..9), but still do not know the procedure which will allow me to evaluate correctness of the user's answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're creating a list of questions with lettered or numbered answers, and you want the user (grandson) to press a key to answer it, rather than enter the answer into an edit field.

Assuming that's correct, you can do one of two things:

- Subclass a widget where you display the questions, and reimplement the keyPressEvent method. Qt calls this method for the widget that gets the keyboard focus. It passes a QKeyEvent objects, which contains the key that was pressed. You can then examine the key to see if it's correct or not, and provide feedback. See the `QWidget::keyPressEvent` documentation for more information.
- Without subclassing, you can create an event filter and install it on a standard widget. The event filter receives the events sent to the target widget, and you can intercept `QKeyEvent` events, inspect them for a correct or incorrect answer and respond accordingly. See the `QObject::installEventFilter` documentation for more information.

Comment: The student is presented with a series of simple addition problems:

Comment: an example... The student is presented with a series of addition problems of the form   3 + x =    where x is represented by the digits 0 through 9.  The first would be 3 + 0 = __  the student types his answer (not using the enter key.  As soon as he hits the 3 key, the next problem appears  3 + 1 = __ and the student types in his answer and the next problem appears.  This continues  for each of the digits 0..9.  I need to wait for each answer, but do not know how to do that without the program freezing up during the wait.

Comment: You don't wait for it. That's not how GUI applications work. Instead of setting up loops where you wait on something, the GUI has an event loop built in that you respond to. One of those events in Qt is a QKeyPress event. The problem with your question is that you're asking for training on an entirely new way of programming, and that's out of scope of this site. You need to get a book on Qt, or look up some tutorials and learn how to do event-driven GUI programming. Trying to convert your console app won't work; you have to redesign it.

Comment: If you do not know the answer, just say so...... 

Do not deflect by putting words in my mouth by saying I am asking for training or need to get book on Qt or look-up tutorials on the internet.  I am not asking for training.  I have read several books on Qt and I have scoured the internet for answers.  I have written a void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event) and can detect each numeric key (0..9), but still do not know the procedure which will allow me to evaluate correctness of the user's answer.  You should not be talking down to anyone who is asking a legitimate question.